# Embed exe of a project into exe of another project and keep it up-to-date

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, project, exe, embedded-resource

I have a solution S with 2 projects, A and B. B needs the exe of A as an embedded resource.

So I right click on B > Add > Add existing item... > I pick `[...]\S\A\bin\debug\A.exe` and for this new item I set Build Action = Embedded Resource.

Everything works well. But if I look to such item's Full Path property I see the path `[...]\S\B\A.exe`. This means that any rebuild of project A won't affect the embedded resource in project B.

**How can I keep embedded resource in project B up-to-date with the original exe resource produced by project A?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is by design.  The IDE normally copies the resource into your project directory, a strong counter-measure to help you avoid some bad day in the future where you can't build your program anymore because the resource is missing and you forgot to make a backup.

Which is not what you want here.  Remove the item and use Add + Existing item again.  Note that there's a down-arrow glyph on the Add button.  Click that arrow and pick "Add as Link".  Now that copy won't be made and your project will refer to the actual file.

You still have to ensure that A.exe is available and up to date before you build B.  Right-click the B project in the Solution Explorer window, Build Dependencies and tick the A project.  A will now always be built before B.